# Understanding what Azure Function running means

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm testing a new Azure function that gets triggered by a message in my storage queue and when I look at it on Azure, I see that its status is "running". My function is running in "Consumption" mode so I just want to make sure I'm interpreting the meaning of "running" correctly.

Is it safe to assume that status running simply means "Ready to Execute" when it receives a message but it's currently **NOT** consuming anything and I'm NOT being charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the running status in the overview page:

[image]

then, you're correct. This just means your application (not any of the functions) is up an running and ready to be used.